# How can I back populate in SQLAlchemy with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

These are the reflected database classes I have, a Resource and Game:

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = Engine

class ResourceDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'resources'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True, 'extend_existing': True}
    resource_id = Column('resource_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    primaryKey = 'resource_id'

class GameDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True, 'extend_existing': True}
    game_id = Column('game_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    primaryKey = 'game_id'
    resource_egm_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("resources.resource_id"))
    resource_vm_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("resources.resource_id"))

    resourceEgmId = relationship("ResourceDB", foreign_keys=[resource_egm_id], lazy="joined", join_depth=1)
    resourceVmId = relationship("ResourceDB", foreign_keys=[resource_vm_id], lazy="joined", join_depth=1)
```

From the Game object, I can reference the 2 Resource objects just fine.

However, what I want to do is reference ALL the games connected to a Resource. As, there may be many games (more than 2) using the same Resource. `resources` table does not have a column for game_id

I have tried to use `back_populates` for each other.

```
# in ResourceDB
games = relationship("GameDB", back_populates="allResources", foreign_keys="[GameDB.resource_egm_id, GameDB.resource_vm_id]")
# in GameDB, replace the 2 relationships with
allResources = relationship("ResourceDB", back_populates="games", foreign_keys=[resource_egm_id, resource_vm_id])
```

resulted in

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ResourceDB.games - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables. Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

If I change the relationship in ResourceDB to using the table name `games`,

```
games = relationship("GameDB", back_populates="Resources", foreign_keys="[games.resource_egm_id, games.resource_vm_id]")
```

I get this:

> One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class ResourceDB->resources'. Original exception was: 'Table' object has no attribute 'resource_egm_id'

::EDIT::
Made some progress.
If I only have relationships in the GameDB and use `backref`, I can get data for the Resource, but since I am using the context manager with the session, I can't get to the data in game.

```
resourceEgmId = relationship("ResourceDB", foreign_keys=[resource_egm_id], backref="gamesEgm", lazy="joined", join_depth=2)
resourceVmId = relationship("ResourceDB", foreign_keys=[resource_vm_id], backref="gamesVm",lazy="joined", join_depth=2)
```

> Parent instance is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'gamesEgm' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)
> I solved this previously by setting the `lazy` parameter to joined, but I can't do that in the ResourceDB class when using backref.

Using postgresql, python 3.7, sqlalchemy 1.4.45

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to create a backref object, which you define the parameters of the relationship of the referenced object.

My final solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, sessionmaker, backref

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = Engine

class ResourceDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'resources'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True, 'extend_existing': True}
    resource_id = Column('resource_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    primaryKey = 'resource_id'

class GameDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True, 'extend_existing': True}
    game_id = Column('game_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    primaryKey = 'game_id'
    resource_egm_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("resources.resource_id"))
    resource_vm_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("resources.resource_id"))

    resourceEgmId = relationship("ResourceDB", foreign_keys=[resource_egm_id], 
                                 lazy="joined", join_depth=1, 
                                 backref=backref("gamesEgm", lazy="joined"))
    resourceVmId = relationship("ResourceDB", foreign_keys=[resource_vm_id], 
                                lazy="joined", join_depth=1,
                                backref=backref("gamesVm", lazy="joined"))
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html#specifying-backref-arguments
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.backref